# Getting formatted result in mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

This is my input table

but i want to  get this table

[image]

Explaination:
I want to  subtract  value  of segmeted 14/10/22 - 7/10/22 that means (28930-28799)

how could i get this kindly help me to figure it out. I cant format it  properly.

[image]

This is my table

and i want to subtract  value  column subtraction by SEGMENTED_DATE wise
like (14th october  value - 7th october value) that means (28930-28799)

the segment table is created by bellow query

```
select segment ,count(distinct user_id)as value,SEGMENTED_DATE  from weekly_customer_RFM_TABLE
     where segment in('About to sleep','Promising','champion','Loyal_customer',
                'Potential_Loyalist','At_Risk','Need_Attention','New_customer',
                'Hibernating','Cant_loose')
     and  SEGMENTED_DATE between '2022-10-07' and '2022-10-28'
Group by segment,SEGMENTED_DATE
```

I want this table as output

[image]

This is only value difference only  Segment_date wise

Comment: the data will always have all the week numbers ?

Comment: especially it is fixed  in 7,14,21,28 dated  value.  it could also be ok with me if the case is  secod week - first week value

Comment: checking but mysql version is 5.6.10 here.  common table format might not work  i guess. Nope this is not working

Comment: which part is not supported

Comment: is the week () function not suported

Comment: yeh it is suppported but i ment ' week2 - week1 ' as just statement string .it is just subtracting  of value column (here second row - first row)

Comment: and lead function is supported only Mysql 8. or above

Comment: Why are you using an outdated, unsupported MySQL version? Upgrade to a current version and such tasks become rather simple. Then, [please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Post your data as formatted text instead. Then, your figures don't match. 28930 - 28799 = 131, not 233. Where does the 344 in the first result row stem from?

Answer (score 0):

The sample data of results table is not correct.
You said that
"I want to subtract value of segmeted 14/10/22 - 7/10/22 that means (28930-28799) " but this gives 131 not 233.
You said that "while in you example and value 21/10/22 -14/10/22 that means(29137-28930)" but this gives 207 not 190.
How did you calculate the value 344 in the first row?

The following query will produce the format you want but without the first row as it is not clear to me how did you calculate it. I put `xxx` AS your table name. The query is based on using variables.

```
SET @Prev = 0;
SET @i = 0;

SELECT CONCAT('Week', C, '-', 'Week', C-1) AS Change_Time, Segment, Prev AS Value FROM (
  SELECT `Value`- @Prev AS Prev, Segment, @Prev :=`Value` AS V, @i:=@i+1 AS C, Segmentd FROM xxx
) AS t WHERE C> 1;
```

The results will be :

[image]

This query is suitable for MySQL engine and will not run on SQL server.

## Edit1:

Here is some explanation:
In inner query I used variables for two reasons:

1. I need a counter (@i) so I can know week index like (week1, week2, ...). This counter will increase with each record by (@i:=@i+1).
2. I need to know value of previous record so I used (@Prev :=`Value`) to save that value then I can subtract it from `Value` in current record (`Value`- @Prev) AS Prev.

I started with initial values (SET @Prev = 0;) Assuming no previous values and (SET @i = 0;) because @i will increased to (1) at first record.

In outer query I converted (@i named C) to (week(i)-week(i-1)) `week1-week0, week2-week1, .......` and removed first record because it will display wrong data.
I can help improving the query if you show me some real data.

## Edit2:

According to you last modification at 2022/10/07 the query will be :

```
SET @Prev = 0;
SET @S = 0;
SELECT Segment, Diffirence, SEGMENTED_DATE FROM (
  SELECT 
    `Value`- @Prev AS Diffirence,  
    POSITION(@S IN Segment) AS NotFirst, 
    @Prev := IF(@S=Segment, `Value`, 0) AS `Value`, 
    @S := Segment AS Segment,
    SEGMENTED_DATE 
  FROM test
) AS t WHERE NotFirst> 0;
```

Comment: sorry that was  not accurate what i have given , i wanted format . your code is working well.  but first  base value in 07/10/2022 for promising segment is giviing me 
-32480 where the actual count is  12547  but the difference  calculation is working 
same goes for new_customer segment where base value  of  7th october count is 
8768 but  showing -5507. can you explain the code  kindly. Thanks for the answer though. I am guessing `Value`- @Prev AS Prev this code is calculated for getting these value

Comment: @kalyan Answer modified with some explain.

Comment: please check my edits . that might clear your concern

Comment: @kalyan answer modified to display the format you want.

Answer (score 0):

You may perform a self join as the following:

```
SET @rn=1;

SELECT T.segment,
       D.value-T.value AS Difference,
       D.segmented_date,
FROM table_name T JOIN table_name D
ON D.segmented_date=T.segmented_date + INTERVAL 7 DAY
   AND D.segment=T.segment
ORDER BY T.segment, D.segmented_date
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/EG0ztqQn).